# Python3 - Nested list/dictionaries iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

After a mongodb request, I get a document like this:

```
a = [{"name": 'Aspirin', "Dates": [{'Qty': 50, 'Date':'2019-07-09'}, {'Qty': 10, 'Date': '2020-05-19'}]}]
```

I would like to retrieve the quantity **50** related to the date **2019-07-09**. This is how I proceed:

```
old_qte = None
for i in a:
    for key, value in i.items():
        if value == 'Aspirin':
            for k, v in i.items():
                if k == 'Dates':
                    for z in v:
                        for x, y in z.items():
                            if y == '2019-07-09':
                                old_qte = z

print(old_qte['Qty'], old_qte)
```

It works very well but it seems very convoluted. Will someone have a simpler and more readable approach?

Comment: Other than breaking the search once you've found the target, don't see much to be trimmed here.

Comment: by making an appropriate MongoDb query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you there in one line:

```
next(date for date in a[0]['Dates'] if date['Date'] == '2019-07-09')['Qty']
#50
```

Will fetch only the first one that satisfies condition and take `Qty` from it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a dict comprehension to reformat the results as a dict that is easier to access (Name -> Date -> Qty)

```py
a = [{"name": 'Aspirin', "Dates": [{'Qty': 50, 'Date': '2019-07-09'}, {'Qty': 10, 'Date': '2020-05-19'}]}]

d = {entry["name"]: {inner["Date"]: inner["Qty"] for inner in entry["Dates"]} for entry in a}

print(d)
print(d["Aspirin"]["2019-07-09"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
a = [{"libelle": 'Aspirine', "Dates": [{'Qte': 50, 'Date':'2019-07-09'}, {'Qte': 10, 'Date': '2020-05-19'}]}]
old_qte = None
for i in a:
    if 'Aspirine' in i.values():
        for j in i["Dates"]:
            if j["Date"] == '2019-07-09':
                old_qte = j["Qte"]
                break

print(old_qte)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a data pipeline where you filter for `Aspirin` first and then check the date:

```
# select 'Aspirin'
r1 = (dct for dct in a if dct["name"] == "Aspirin")
# unpack 'Dates' lists
r2 = (date for item in r1 for date in item["Dates"])
# select date
r3 = (dct for dct in r2 if dct["Date"] == "2019-07-09")

next(r3)  # {'Qty': 50, 'Date': '2019-07-09'}
```